# Mysql unique rows with proper counts for different columns

Tags: php, mysql, select, count

My table is set up with the following columns:

`id - game_id - player_id - action - assist`

Where action displays the type of action performed (goal, assist, freekick) and assist is filled with the player_id of the player giving the assist (if present). Some player_id's have more rows for different actions within one game.

Each row is therefore filled with for example:

`1 - 3 - 15 - goal - 5`

I now would like to create an overview that sums all actions per player_id so I have only one row per player_id in my result array. I have done this with the following query which seems to work for me:

`SELECT id, player_id, game_id, assist, action, COUNT(*) AS count FROM game_action WHERE game_id = 3 GROUP BY player_id`

In some rows there is however a value present in the assist column. I would like to also retrieve that players' information and list it as a separate row with the proper count for 'assist'.

How would I go about this? Or would it be more wise to change the way my table-structure and saving of records is set up?

Comment: group by both the columns ? Eg. `GROUP BY player_id, assist`

Comment: That doesn't seem to do the trick @jitendrapurohit. Thanks for your suggestion though!

Comment: Please give an example of what kind of output you want.

Comment: Right now I have an array like this for every player.

    Array
    (
    [id] => 7
    [player_id] => 18
    [game_id] => 3
    [action] => goal
    [count] => 2
    )

If in one row in the table the column 'assist' has a value though, I also want to generate a new result row/array for that player_id. He/she could have more assists within one game.

Comment: _“I have done this with the following query which seems to work for me”_ – exactly, it only _seems_ to work. You can not select columns that are not part of the grouping. MySQL tolerates this (if the server config says so), but the values you will be getting for these columns will be from a “random” row. Don’t do this - even if it _seems_ to work now, you might get different results for the same data at any point.

Answer (score 0):

What about union ? example :

```
SELECT id, player_id, game_id, assist, action, COUNT(*) AS count 
FROM game_action 
WHERE game_id = 3 GROUP BY player_id 
union 
SELECT id, player_id, game_id, assist, action,count(*) 
from game_action 
where player_id in (select assist from game_action where game_id = 3) 
GROUP BY player_id
```